# Dualboot Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04, Dell XPS 15 Installation Problems

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation, xps

I've been trying to setup a dual boot dell xps 15 with both windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04.  I purchased the computer recently, and I am using the official USB stick from canonical to install it.  I've followed this guide step by step, using the section 'If you have a OEM-preinstalled copy of Windows 8 or later':

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343370#343370)

I am able to make it up to the final step, but when I click the install now button I am immediately hit with errno5 Input/Output, which recommends I clean my CD (Which I'm not using).

I should also mention that I've turned off Secure Boot in the UEFI options, and switched my computer to AHCI mode.  I did this to circumvent the problem of the ubuntu installer not being able to see the free, unallocated space I made for it in my storage (it would give the error "Ubuntu needs 8.4 GB to install, you have 8.2 GB).

Thanks in advance to whomever responds to this!

Comment: You need to be installing in UEFI boot mode. But how large are you making / (root) partition. With new larger drives I suggest 25GB if saving data in separate /home or using a shared NTFS data partition for most data. Otherwise even larger /.  Dell threads: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317843 Dell Xps 15 9550  Ubuntu 15.10 on new Infinity display (i7 6gen 16gbr UHD 4k touch) post 272 says 16.04 good
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2301071

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I am booting in UEFI mode, only with the secureboot option turned off.  The root partition is 110 GB while the swap is 15 GB, which I figure should be big enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I was able to solve the problem.  What I did was to update the BIOS drivers to the most recent version, reinstall Ubuntu 16.04.1 to the USB, and follow the directions in the https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317843 thread.  Hope this helps someone!